# sql select only if found more than once

Tags: sql, select, count

I have a table with userid and feature. I want to select only those users with more than 1 feature selected. check out the table

```
    declare @tbl table (userid int, feature nvarchar(10))
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 1, 'abc'
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 1, 'xyz'
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 2, 'abc'
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 3, 'abc'
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 3, 'xyz'
    insert into @tbl(userid, feature)
    select 3, 'pqr'
```

[image]

My query should only return the count = 2 (userids 1 and 3 as they both have multiple features associated). In other words I want the count of userids with multiple features associated with them.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `JOIN` with condition aggregate function in `HAVING`

```
SELECT t1.userid
FROM @tbl t1
INNER JOIN @tbl t2 
ON t1.feature = t2.feature
AND t1.userid <> t2.userid
GROUP BY t1.userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.feature) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple aggregation: group by user and count.

```
select userid
from @tbl
group by userid
having count(*) > 1;
```